# Unable to find the application support folder for a specified application inside an Apple Script

Tags: applescript

I have an apple script that asks the user to select an application as a prompt. I would like to know how it could be possible to find the directory of the Application Support folder for this application per example, Spotify is
`~/Library/Application Support/Spotify/`

On my mac, but like is there a way inside apple script to find this directory for the specific app. It would really be appreciated, thanks!

Because I would like to then delete this folder using Apple Script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should accomplish what you're looking to achieve.  Be careful though because using `System Events` to `delete`... deletes the item permanently instead of sending it to the `Trash`

```
property folderNames : missing value

tell application "System Events"
    set appSupportFolder to application support folder
    set folderNames to name of folders of appSupportFolder
    set theChoice to my chooseFolderToDelete()
    delete folder theChoice of appSupportFolder
end tell

to chooseFolderToDelete()
    activate
    set theChoice to (choose from list folderNames with prompt ¬
        "Select an Application's Support folder to delete" OK button name ¬
        "Delete Folder" cancel button name "Cancel") as text
end chooseFolderToDelete
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works for me, thank you for helping me but do you think there is a way to select like the app and find the corresponding application support folder of that app instead of having to select the folder manually?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  Are you looking to do something like selecting the app in Finder, then maybe hitting some sort of assigned keyboard shortcut to automatically delete the corresponding app's application support folder?

Comment: Yes kind of, but not delete the app, but delete the app's corresponding Application support folder